# Google Translate API returns non UTF8 characters

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, utf-8, google-api, google-translation-api

**Resolve**
See in the end of this post for the solution

Good evening.

Im trying to play with the google translate v3 api.

And I arrive on a mystical encoding issue.

I do this :

```
def translate_text_langueTarget(texteToTranslate, langueTarget):
     parent = client.location_path(project_id, location)
     langueOrigin = detect_language(texteToTranslate)
     if (langueOrigin == "en" and langueTarget == "en"):
         return(texteToTranslate)
     try:
         response = client.translate_text(
             parent=parent,
             contents=[texteToTranslate],
             mime_type='text/plain',
             source_language_code=langueOrigin,
             target_language_code=langueTarget)
         translatedTexte = str(response.translations)[19:-3]
     except:
         translatedTexte = "Sorry my friend, the translation is lost on the internet"

     print(response)
     print(type(response))
     print(response.translations)
     print(type(response.translations))
     return(translatedTexte)
```

I call this with

```
stringToTrad = "prefer"
langTarget = "fr"
translateString = translate_text_langueTarget(stringToTrad, langTarget)
```

And I expecte to have "préféré" in answer

But I obtain :
"pr\303\251f\303\251rer"

I have try to look after this error with a bit of debug in my code, with :

```
print(response)
print(type(response))
print(response.translations)
print(type(response.translations))
```

I think it's a problem of encoding but i can't find a answer to my problem.

I work in python and my scrip is tag :

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8
```

in the header

Do you have an idea ?

**Resolve.**
I use :

```
translatedTexte = codecs.escape_decode(translatedTexte)[0]
translatedTexte = translatedTexte.decode("utf8")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API of Google Translate gives you UTF-8 text.
You got `c3 a9` (303 251 as octal numbers) which it is really `é`, as expected.

So your code take the correct UTF-8 file and it writes it as maybe wrong encoding.

This line is just a myth, not useful:

```
# coding: utf-8
```

If you want that your code interpret input and output as UTF-8, you should explicitly say so.  With your code, I assume that (one problem) is that you use print (better to write into a file). On Windows, by default, terminals are not UTF-8, but old "Windows ANSI like and extended also know as Windows 1252" encoding.

So write into a file (with explicit UTF-8 encoding), or just change terminal settings, to have UTF-8 terminal. In addition, you may have escape sequences, on results. To me, it smell much, to have results written in octal way. Not a think of standard Python (and it will complain, about wrong encoding). You may need to parse the response, to translate escape sequences.

Comment: First tanks for your help.
I simplify my problem when i ask this question.
I dont wont to print in it in a terminal.
This was just for debug.

I wok in a flask api.
I try to make api who parse json comments
{
    "id=1694639": "Je préfère le bleu que le rouge"
}
Translate them in english for work purpose with patter library.
Then i re-translate them in their origin language.

Last i send a response.
A i obtain this with postman when i want to test my api.

  "pr\\303\\251f\\303\\251rer": 1,
  "pr\\303\\251f\\303\\251rer_id": [
    "1694639"
  ]
 How to output them in utf8 ?

Comment: Have you looked the API documentation. You uses just the output, without parsing. The magic `[19:-3]` smell. Please parse the output properly, and you get your proper string.

Comment: I resolve my problem with thuis

translatedTexte = codecs.escape_decode(translatedTexte)[0]
translatedTexte = translatedTexte.decode("utf8")

I search for this for 4h and i nerver see the codecs side of my problem.

I look at it thanks to your "interpret input and output as UTF-8, you should explicitly say so"

Thanks a lot.

Comment: "# coding: utf-8" *is* useful.  It declares the encoding of the *Python source file* but has nothing to do with the encoding of files, sockets, databases, etc.'

Comment: @MarkTolonen: it is default, and so it is not used if there are strong suggestion that that UTF-8 is not the right encoding. So skipping such line could only improve things (e.g. copying/pasting code). The problem with that line: too many people here suggest it as solution of encoding problems (which it is not), so that line is also cause of problems.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the response from the API is html encoded (so it is UTF-8 wrapped in html encoding, also used for URL encoding).

The solution is simple.

```
import html

print(sf)
# Vinken rejoindra le conseil d&#39;administration en novembre.

print(html.unescape(sf))
# Vinken rejoindra le conseil d'administration en novembre.
```

+Info https://stackoverflow.com/a/48805931/4752223

Comment: Thanx a lot . I have resolve my probleme with a "magic trick" but you have the perfect answer.
Thank a lot.